# CS0117 Form1 does not contain a definition for application. (Windows studio 2019)

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to close an Excel workbook, but I get the CS0117 error 'type' does not contain a definition for 'identifier' on "application" the code I used is as follows in "btnExcelClose_Click"

```
    private void btnExcelClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the file name
        object fileName = "FoodPantry.xlsx";
        //Get the file
        Excel.Workbook workbook = Form1.Application.Workbooks.get_Item(fileName);
        //Close the workbook
        workbook.Close(false);
    }

   private void btExcelOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Get fully qualified path for xlsx file
        string excelWB = (@"C:\Users\User-123\Documents\Food Pantry\Working Backups\FoodPantry.xlsx");

        var exApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var exWbk = exApp.Workbooks.Open(excelWB);
        exApp.Visible = true;

    }
```

Comment: Why would a winforms [`Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=net-5.0) contain a reference to an instance of Excel? If you created an instance of Excel and saved it into a variable, refer to that variable.

Comment: It lets me open the workbook but not close it.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You are not using `Form1.Application` in `btExcelOpen_Click` to create Excel. You are using the `new` operator and you are storing the result in `exApp`. So it's `exApp` that you must call `.Workbooks.get_Item(fileName)` on.

Comment: The variable exWbk is inside a method btExcelOpen_Click and is not accessaible to the method brnExcelClose_Click.  The solution is to move the definition of the varible exWbk to global space outside any method so it is accessible to boththe Open and Close method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Declare exApp as Form's global variable.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exApp;

private void btExcelOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get fully qualified path for xlsx file
            string excelWB = (@"D:\sts_device.xlsx");

            exApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); 
            var exWbk = exApp.Workbooks.Open(excelWB);
            exApp.Visible = true;
        }
private void  btnExcelClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            exApp.Workbooks.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I did as you said, now I have a working close.

Comment: That's great. Upvote to your effort.